# store output of function into a new column of dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, storage

I have this code below. I want to push the output of y[1] + (y[2]/60) into a new column in x. This is probably really simple, I am not seeing it. Thanks for the help.

```
read.table(file=file.choose(),header=T)
x$AverageTime<- as.character(x$AverageTime)
sapply(strsplit(x$Average,":"),
       function(y) {
         y <- as.numeric(y)
     y[1] + (y[2]/60)
       }
)
```

Comment: dplyr::mutate may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just put in "x$newcolumn <- " before your sapply command to get the new column.

```
read.table(file=file.choose(),header=T)
x$AverageTime<- as.character(x$AverageTime)
x$newcolumn <- sapply(strsplit(x$Average,":"),
                     function(y) {y <- as.numeric(y)
                                  y[1] + (y[2]/60)})
```